# Trouble deleting a 2d array in a template class

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, dynamic, netbeans

So I have been working on a program where I utilize 2d arrays and
templates to print out matrices on Netbeans 8.2. I only allowed to
write the implementation files.(i.e. I am not allowed to add into/ditch functions from the header files or main.)

Ideally, if the class object is of type int, it will print a 2d array which is populated by random integer numbers; if the class object is of type float, it will print a 2d array that is populated by random floats. So far I have been successful in getting the output of the 2D array, and the result seems legit. However, I keep getting this exception "0 [main] review3_cis17c_template_ 302
cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to review3_cis17c_template_.exe.stackdump", which I believe has to do with me using the delete key wrong in Table.h.

What is causing the trouble? I could not find anything wrong in my mechanism of allocating memory. I will post my Table.h, RowAray.h, and main.cpp since they are all coherent.

Here is my RowAray.h:

```
#ifndef ROWARAY_H
#define ROWARAY_H
#include<iostream>

template<class T>
class RowAray{
    protected:
        int size;
        T *rowData;
    public:
        RowAray(int);
        virtual ~RowAray();
        int getSize()const{return size;}
        T getData(int i)const{
            if(i>=0&&i<size)return rowData[i];
            else return 0;}
        void setData(int,T);
};

#include <cstdlib>

template<class T> 
RowAray<T>::RowAray(int r) {
    size = r;

    rowData = new T[r];

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        rowData[i] = static_cast<T>(rand() % 90 + 10);
    }
}

template<class T>
RowAray<T>::~RowAray() {
    delete []rowData;
}

template<class T>
void RowAray<T>::setData(int i, T value) {
    rowData[i] = value;
}
#endif /* ROWARAY_H */
```

Here is my Table.h:

```
#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H
#include "RowAray.h"

template<class T>
class Table{
    protected:
        int szRow;
        int szCol;
        RowAray<T> **columns;
    public:
        Table(unsigned int,unsigned int);
        Table(const Table<T> &);
        virtual ~Table();
        int getSzRow()const {return szRow;}
        int getSzCol()const {return szCol;}
        T getData(int,int)const;
        void setData(int,int,T);
        Table<T> operator+(const Table<T> &);
};

template<class T>
Table<T>::Table(unsigned int r, unsigned int c) {
    szRow = r;
    szCol = c;

    columns = new RowAray<T>*[r];

    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        columns[i] = new RowAray<T>(c);
    }
}

template<class T>
Table<T>::Table(const Table<T> &t) {
    szRow = t.getSzRow();
    szCol = t.getSzCol();

    columns = new RowAray<T>*[t.getSzRow()];

    for(int i = 0; i < t.getSzRow(); i++) {
        columns[i] = new RowAray<T>(t.getSzCol());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < t.getSzRow(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < t.getSzCol(); j++) {
            columns[i]->setData(j, t.getData(i, j));
        }
    }
}

template<class T>
T Table<T>::getData(int r, int c) const {
    return columns[r]->getData(c);
}

template<class T>
Table<T>::~Table() {
    for (int i = 0; i < szRow; i++) {
       delete []columns;
    }

    delete columns;
}

template<class T> 
Table<T> Table<T>::operator+(const Table<T> &t) {
    Table<T> tab(t.getSzRow(), t.getSzCol());

    for(int i = 0; i < t.getSzRow(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <t.getSzCol(); j++) {
            tab.columns[i]->setData(j, this->getData(i,j) + t.getData(i,j));
        }
    }

    return tab;
}
#endif /* TABLE_H */
```

And finally, my main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//User Libraries
#include "Table.h"

//Global Constants

//Function Prototype
template<class T>
void prntRow(RowAray<T> *,int);
template<class T>
void prntTab(const Table<T> &);

//Execution Begins Here!
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   //Initialize the random seed
   srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

   //Declare Variables
   int rows=3,cols=4;

   //Test out the Row with integers and floats
   RowAray<int> a(3);RowAray<float> b(4);
   cout<<"Test the Integer Row "<<endl;
   prntRow(&a,3);
   cout<<"Test the Float Row "<<endl;
   prntRow(&b,4);

   //Test out the Table with a float
   Table<float> tab1(rows,cols);
   Table<float> tab2(tab1);
   Table<float> tab3=tab1+tab2;

   cout<<"Float Table 1 size is [row,col] = ["
           <<rows<<","<<cols<<"]";
   prntTab(tab1);

   cout<<"Float Table 2 size is [row,col] = ["
           <<rows<<","<<cols<<"]";
   prntTab(tab2);

   cout<<"Float Table 3 size is [row,col] = Table 1 + Table 2 ["
           <<rows<<","<<cols<<"]";
    prntTab(tab3);

   //Exit Stage Right
   return 0;
}

template<class T>
void prntRow(RowAray<T> *a,int perLine){
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<showpoint<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<a->getSize();i++){
        cout<<a->getData(i)<<" ";
        if(i%perLine==(perLine-1))cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

template<class T>
void prntTab(const Table<T> &a){
    cout<<fixed<<setprecision(1)<<showpoint<<endl;
    for(int row=0;row<a.getSzRow();row++){
        for(int col=0;col<a.getSzCol();col++){
            cout<<setw(8)<<a.getData(row,col);
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

This is my first time posting, so I sincerely apologize if the codes are messy. Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: You could/should have made `columns` in the `Table` class a `RowAray<RowAray<T>>` instead of `RowAray<T>**`,  That cuts down on all of that code you have in `Table` now that attempts to do dynamic allocation of `RowAray`.  Then all of the dynamic allocation routines are isolated to the `RowAray` class, and any bugs would be found there.

Comment: In addition, your `RowAray` needs to implement a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator.  Once you have those two functions working properly, then `Table` will automatically work (if you used what I suggested in my first comment).

Comment: But if you want to (or have to) do this the hard way, I'm betting you can chew the problem down to size fairly quickly with the GDB frontend built into Netbeans. Build a debug executable, run it in GDB via Netbeans, wait for the crash and gather information when the debugger halts. Use the information gathered to decide where you want to look next, place a breakpont there, run the program again. Continue until problem solved.

Comment: Your `Table` destructor looks strange: `for (int i = 0; i < szRow; i++) {delete []columns;}`.  What is being deleted here?  You're deleting the same thing over and over again in a loop.  But again, this is not necessary if you delegated all of the dynamic memory management to `RowAray` (which you really should do).

Comment: Also, your `RowAray<T>::getData` returns 0 if the size is out-of-bounds.  This is confusing, since there is no indication the index is out-of-bounds, and if you had something like `RowAray<std::string>`, then there is no conversion to `0`.  Better just throw an exception without returning anything.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you so much for your comments! I agree with all of your suggestions but unfortunately, I am not allowed to modify any of the class members. I would have to bite the bullet and do them as they were, but I definitely find your comments helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Also, to answer your question of what is being deleted by the for loop: it deletes the arrays built on the double pointer. After it runs out of the for loop, it deletes the entire pointer.

Comment: @VincentReeve -- *it deletes the arrays built...* -- No it doesn't.  Look at the loop carefully.  You are deleting the very same pointer over and over again.  There is no invariant in that line in the loop.  That loop should be `delete columns [i];`.  Note the `i` in that loop?  Your current code causes a double deletion error, and you are lucky your code didn't simply crash there.  Then the last line *after* the loop should have been `delete [] columns;`.